# What does error "redefinition of formal parameter" mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++

C++ beginner here with a functions error, I get the error "redefinition of formal parameter". What does this mean? and how can I fix it.

```
int getGuessFromUser(int guess)
{
    std::cout << "Guess my lucky number between 0 and 10: ";
    int guess;
    std::cin >> guess;
    return guess;
}
```

Comment: It means you have a formal parameter `guess` which exists already as an argument to your function `int getGuessFromUser(int guess)`, but you are attempting to redefine it as local variable in the line `int guess;`.

Comment: `int getGuessFromUser(int guess)` declares `int guess` and then you do it again with `int guess;` Get rid of `int guess;` inside the function.

Comment: Probably your function shouldn't even take an argument `int guess` because it doesn't seem to use it (as in: read from it), nor would it even make sense for it given its name "**get** guess".

Comment: Note: One of the first things a good tester will do with this function is input "ABC" for their guess. Your program will fail and stay failed. Read up on *Input Validation* for ideas on how to outfox the tester.

Answer (score 1):

You have a parameter `int guess` and a variable `int guess`

You don't seem to be using the parameter, so perhaps remove it?

```
int getGuessFromUser()
{
    std::cout << "Guess my lucky number between 0 and 10: ";
    int guess;
    std::cin >> guess;
    return guess;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I'am still very new to programming, but Iam not using the parameter int guess below the std::cout?

Comment: No, that's the other `int guess` - the one you declare in the middle of the function

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have already declared the parameter guess in you getGuessFromUser function. You do not need to declare it again, so you can remove the line `int guess`

Answer (score 0):

You have a function parameter named `guess` and also a local variable with the exact same name.

This would be just like declaring two variables with the same name in the same scope (like a function), which is not allowed.

Change one of the names to remove the error.